# How to access selected value from the code behind in drop down list defined inside edititemtemplate using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownlist inside an Edititemtemplate. I want to access the selected value from code behind.

My aspx

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select Country" Value="0" disabled selected></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="india" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

My aspx.cs

```
 protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
    //I want to access the dropdown value here//
    }
```

Comment: Try `string country = ((DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlcountry")).SelectedValue;`

Comment: @Suprabhat:It doesn't work,is there is any other way?keyword 'Item' doesn't work

Comment: @Suprabhat:yes,'item' does not supporting,it shows error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
DropDownList ddlCountries = (ListView.EditItem.FindControl("ddlcountry") as DropDownList);
if(ddlCountries!=null)
 {
string value=ddlCountries.SelectedValue;
}
}
```

Comment: :It doesn't work,is there is any other way?keyword 'Item' doesn't work

Comment: ,thank you for your reply,now i can get the value.but i want the text,ie the country name

Comment: @hakkeem, use selected item intend of  selected value.